# Wrong systemTimeZone

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nstimezone

I'm trying to get systemTimeZone, but it gives me wrong data:

```
NSTimeZone * currentDateTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSString* name = [currentDateTimeZone name];
int myGMT = (int)roundf([currentDateTimeZone secondsFromGMT]/60.f/60.f);
```

I'm living in Budapest,Hungary. It's in GMT+1, but I'm getting `myGMT = 2.`
But name is ok : `name = Europe/Budapest`
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current GMT offset for the Europe/Budapest timezone is GMT+2, because
the [*Daylight Saving Time*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) started at Sunday, 30 March 2014, and the clocks were
advanced by one hour (see http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=50).

You can verify that with

```
BOOL isDst = [currentDateTimeZone isDaylightSavingTime];
// --> YES
NSTimeInterval dstOffset = [currentDateTimeZone daylightSavingTimeOffset];
// --> 3600
```

If necessary, you can compute

```
[currentDateTimeZone secondsFromGMT] - [currentDateTimeZone daylightSavingTimeOffset]
```

to get the "default" GMT offset for your timezone.

Comment: So if I use it like this:     int myGMT = [currentDateTimeZone secondsFromGMT] - [currentDateTimeZone daylightSavingTimeOffset];
    myGMT = (int)roundf(myGMT/60.f/60.f); It will give me the right GMT ALL TIME, ALL SPACE ?

Comment: @incmiko: That depends on what you mean by "right GMT".

Comment: For example,I want at Budapest all time GMT+1

Comment: @incmiko: Yes, that would give the same result independent of the current date, e.g. GMT+1 for Budapest.